# What statistics books would you recommend for an undergraduate student who wants to be a machine learning engineer?

Tags: statistics, book-recommendation, machine-learning

I'm an undergraduate software engineering student and I will be taking a statistics course in this semester. I was thinking of buying a statistics textbook such as Probability and Statistics for Engineers and Scientists by Jay Devore, then I came across with some statistics books for programmers and data scientists.

1-) Think Stats: Probability and Statistics for Programmers

2-) Think Bayes: Bayesian Statistics in Python

3-) Practical Statistics for Data Scientists: 50+ Essential Concepts

I want to learn statistics for improving my understanding of machine learning. Which books would you recommend for that purpose ?

Comment: I would recommend All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman.

Comment: Python for probability, statistics, machine learning by Unpingco.

Comment: An Introduction to Statistical Learning by James et al is one book to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

The following book on Statistical Methods might be of help for you. It covers the following contents and uses R software in carrying out statistical tests

Descriptive Statistical Tools
Probability and Probability Distributions
Sampling
Estimation and Statistical Inference
Analysis of Variance
Correlation and Regression
Sensitivity, Specificity, Predictive value, risk & odds ratio and ROC curve 87
Bayesian and Frequentist approach to Statistics
Non Parametric Tests
Advanced Statistical Models

Title : [Introduction to Statistical Methods](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0868TWQ6M)
ISBN: 9798629947158